# Why can't I access the image in JSP file using realpath?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a sample index.jsp file and in the same directory I also have 1.png.

These all work when I access the jsp file, I can see the image I have

```
<img src="1.png"/>
<img src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/1.png"/>
```

But this does not work fine:

```
<img src="<%= request.getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator)%>1.png"/>
```

When I inspect the source I see:

```
<img src="C:\tomcat\webapps\multi-web\1.png"/>
```

and this is where the image really is. But in the browser I can not see the image. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that would open a file located on the end-user machine, and not on the web server. The browser won't let an HTML page do that: it would represent a security hole.

Comment: Thanks, great answer as usual. But if I run this code in a class, then it will find the file in the server right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "running this code in a class". Whether the HTML page has been generated by a JSP, a class or a bunch of monkeys typing randomly doesn't change anything for the browser. It will refuse to load an image from a local file.

Comment: I meant like reaching the file from a servlet.

Comment: Yes, you can (and should, if the file is not part of the webapp) provide a servlet that will open the file, read it, and send the bytes to the browser. Your HTML markup will point to this servlet rather than pointing to the file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Image can't be access with real path of location by Server, because html page will be run User browser. Image should be access with server URL.